# Restrict QLineEdit input to single character PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a PyQt5 application. I want to restrict the user to be able to enter only a single character in a QLineEdit object. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QLineEdit has the maxLength property.

> **setMaxLength()**
>
> Sets the maximum number of characters for input

```
e1 = QLineEdit()
e1.setMaxLength(1)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that I helped :)